# Azure publish profile Target Framework .NET Core 3.0 unavaiable

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, deployment, blazor-client-side

I created a Web App on Azure portal, on runtime stack option I chose ".NET Core 3.0".
When I import publish settings of this WebApp to VS2019, in Publish Profile summary I see "netstandard2.1".Is that normal, shouldn't it be 'netcoreapp3.0' ?

[image: VS2019 publish profile settings]

In AppService settings > Configuration > [tab] General settings:

Stack: .NET

.NET Framework version: V4.7

[image: Azure WebApp settings]

How is it possible? The app that I am deploying was created as **Blazor WebAssembly App** template (CLI: .NET Core 3.1.102)

Comment: If your stack says ".Net" and shows a Framework version, then it did not get created as a .Net Core app, but as a Framework app.  It should list the Stack as ".NET Core" and no Framework.  Either Azure messed up or you selected something by mistake.  If you want to precreate the app on the portal (and not have VS do it), then I would suggest deleting and recreating this app again.  Something is off.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your  Blazor WebAssembly App and click `Edit Project File`.

Change

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

To

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The target framework will turn to .net core, and republish the webapp.

[image]

Comment: I changed it. I got 2 errors: [I] ILLink exitcode -532462766 [II] Mono.Linker.Steps.XmlResolutionException...

Comment: The target framework is your local project framework. It is not related with your publish profile.